# Collapsing bootstrap table with select

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a bootstrap table where I get the values from my database using select:

```
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Studentnamn</th>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      <th>Registrerade kurser</th>
      <th>Betyg</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php include 'studentDB.php'; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I want to make my table collapse and then display an inputform where the values on onclicked row can be updated. I have used following code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT student.studName, grades.studId, grades.courseId, grades.grade FROM student
        INNER JOIN grades ON student.studId=grades.studId";

try {

    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUpdate">';
        echo '<td>' . $row['studName'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['studId'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['courseId'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['grade'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow" id="collapseRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="collapseUpdate">
              <div class="card card-block">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="update.php" method="post" id="newGrade">

                  <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Nytt betyg:</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <p><input id="cbetyg" name="grade" type="text"></p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="studId" value="'. $row['studId'] .'">
                        <input type="hidden" name="courseId" value="'. $row['courseId'] .'">
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-actions">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ändra">
                  </div>
                </form>
```

My problem here is now that, only the first row collapses and can use update. When I click on the other rows, the first row collapses... Can somebody tell me what I can do? And also, will my update still work for each individual row if I make the collapse work for all the rows?

[My table looks like this (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcqxD.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `collapseUpdate` target in any field. Try modify these lines:

instead

```
echo '<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUpdate">';
```

use

```
echo '<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUpdate'.$row['studId'].'">';
```

and instead

```
echo '<td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow" id="collapseRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="collapseUpdate">
```

use

```
echo '<td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow" id="collapseRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="collapseUpdate'.$row['studId'].'">
```

I suspect that `studId` is unique in this table.

Comment: It worked! Thank you a lot!! :D You are my lifesavior :)

Comment: I remembered that my PK is a combination of studId and courseId, so how do I do now? Because studId wasn't unique and when a studId is clicked only the previous row (with the same studId) is collapsing...

Comment: You can use `$row['studId'].'_'.$row['courseId']` instead of `$row['studId']`.